# Porting data structures from Python to JS

Tags: javascript, python, node.js

I'm building a node application to read Blizzard's MOBA game 'Heroes of the Storm' replay files. Blizzard has provided a replay parser called `heroprotocol` and a gentleman later ported it a `nodejs` version he dubbed `heroprotocoljs`. However he has stopped maintaining the repository a year ago and the replay versions continue to change.

Ultimately I need a way to port the data structures from a python format like [this](https://github.com/Blizzard/heroprotocol/blob/master/protocol40431.py) to a javascript format like [this](https://github.com/Farof/heroprotocoljs/blob/master/lib/protocol40431.js).

I've tried `pyjs`, `javascripthon`, and `transcrypt`. None of them seem to produce the desired result about what I'm after. These formats are very similar and a near 1-to-1 translation should be possible even if I have to resort to using regular expressions to convert it line by line.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried exporting those structures as json? That might be what you're looking for. You can use something like this:

```
import json

typeinfos = [
             ('_int',[(0,7)]),  #0
             ('_int',[(0,4)]),  #1
            # ...
            ]

with open("hero.json", "w") as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(typeinfos))
```